# How to check if there is a special character in string or if a character is a special character in GoLang

Tags: string, go, special-characters

After reading a string from the input, I need to check if there is a special character in it

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on what do you mean by special character in golang?

Comment: characters like these: '/', '-', '|' ,'&'

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I ended up doing something like this

```
alphabet := "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
alphabetSplit := strings.Split(alphabet, "")
inputLetters := strings.Split(input, "")

for index, value := range inputLetters {
        special:=1
        for _, char :=range alphabetSplit{
            if char == value {
                special = 0
                break
            }
        }
```

It might have anything wrong because since I used it to something specific i had to edit to post it here

Comment: That's a lot of extra work to just iterate over a string.

Comment: That won't allow for uppercase characters, characters with diacritics like `é`, `ñ` and `ç`, non-Latin scripts. Basically anything that's not English won't pass.

Answer (score 17):

You can use strings.ContainsAny to see if a rune exists:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "strings"
)

func main() {
  fmt.Println(strings.ContainsAny("Hello World", ",|"))
  fmt.Println(strings.ContainsAny("Hello, World", ",|"))
  fmt.Println(strings.ContainsAny("Hello|World", ",|"))
}
```

Or if you want to check if there are only ASCII characters, you can use strings.IndexFunc:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    f := func(r rune) bool {
        return r < 'A' || r > 'z'
    }
    if strings.IndexFunc("HelloWorld", f) != -1 {
        fmt.Println("Found special char")
    }
    if strings.IndexFunc("Hello World", f) != -1 {
        fmt.Println("Found special char")
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up checking everything that wasn't ABC...Z

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your definition of *special character*, the simplest solution would probably to do a `for range` loop on your string (which yield runes instead of bytes), and for each rune check if it is in your list of allowed/forbidden runes.

See [Strings, bytes, runes and characters in Go](https://blog.golang.org/strings) for more about the relations between string, bytes and runes.

[Playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/3OueP8kIEz)

```
package main

var allowed = []rune{'a','b','c','d','e','f','g'}

func haveSpecial(input string) bool {
    for _, char := range input {
        found := false
        for _, c := range allowed {
            if c == char {
                found = true
                break
            }
        }
        if !found {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

func main() {
    cases := []string{
        "abcdef",
        "abc$€f",
    }
    for _, input := range cases {
        if haveSpecial(input) {
            println(input + ": NOK")
        } else {
            println(input + ": OK")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you change `allowed` to a map you get O(1) access instead

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the unicode package, which has a nice function to check for symbols.

https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/#IsSymbol

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unicode"
)

func hasSymbol(str string) bool {
    for _, letter := range str {
        if unicode.IsSymbol(letter) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

func main() {   
    var strs = []string {
        "A quick brown fox",
        "A+quick_brown<fox",
    }

    for _, str := range strs {
        if hasSymbol(str) { 
            fmt.Printf("String '%v' contains symbols.\n", str)
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("String '%v' did not contain symbols.\n", str)   
        }
    }
}
```

This will provide the following output:

```
String 'A quick brown fox' did not contain symbols.
String 'A+quick_brown<fox' contains symbols.
```

Comment: This works for unicode characters like +, <, etc but won't give the correct output for escape sequences like `\n`, etc.

Comment: @Nikhita Based on Kipz' comment on the main question, he was not worried about escape characters. Nor were they mentioned in the question. This would likely have been the best solution for the problem.